# Changing the discussion guide halfway through a round of interviews

Tags: user-interviews

Will adding new questions to an interview discussion guide, halfway through a round of discovery interviews, cause potential for misaligned results at the end?

Comment: Yes, you will get misaligned results. But given that you're actually changing the discussion halfway, I need to ask you why? Because that would change the answer altogether. At this point, i feel like this question would get polarized answers

Comment: @ShreyasTripathy , the question is about methodology. So you're correct about the misaligned results and how new answers will impact on old answers (as pointed in my answer), but the reasons why Op wants to do this are irrelevant, methodology will still be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most situations, yes. You'll need to measure this in some way, so adding more (or changing) questions will obviously provide different results.

However, this doesn't mean it's wrong to do this. Any procedure that helps you get better insights is a good procedure. If you feel like some questions need to be added, then go for it. Just be careful not to mix results from your first interviews and your second batch. This is specially needed if these new questions are going to have some effect over answers, so to save you time, just consider them as separate tests and combine results afterwards.

Comment: Thanks all - thanks Devin again ;-)

We've done a few 'dry runs' with our guide and then set the questions ready for the interviews. I believe Devin, you're right in that its ok to add questions but being careful not to mix those first round of interview findings with those with the new guide - equals two rounds. 

Little bit of background, we're finding out whether a resource is need for the NHS UK for T1 diabetes. We'll find out if we need 'something' or not as it could be the case. Thanks for your advice and time.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a justified reason for the change- I would say it is okay to make changes. And once you have made the change, keep that consistent for the rest of the cycle of interviews. Have you done a pilot before you started? I found that a first couple of rounds of interviews (pilot) with the guide always pays dividends.